# Change UISearchBar text color in tvOS 10

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, tvos10

UISearchBar default text colour is black colour in UISearchController.
How can we change the UISearchController UISearchBar text colour to white colour in tvOS10

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for my issue.
Setting "User Interface Style" property to "Dark" in plist solved the problem

Comment: I have fixed it with the help of plist. But it is effecting another place.